# why does "printing" occurs before "returning"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Code:

```
def f0():
    return 1

def f1():
    print("I don't deserve to be first :(")

print(f0(), f1())
```

Expected Output:

```
1 I don't deserve to be first :(
None
```

Actual Output:

```
I don't deserve to be first :(
1 None
```

I think it has to do something with the default behaviour of `sys.__stdout__`

Where exactly in Python Documention I  can find details which are relevant to my question is what I am interested in.

Or may be someone to explain directly here (?)

Comment: @kindall's answer does a good job explaining here, but to get the expected output (I'm assuming you're not actually looking for the `None`, do :

    def f0():
        return 1

    def f1():
        return "I don't deserve to be first :("

    print(f0(), f1())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Has nothing to do with stdout, but rather with when values are printed. Your `f0` is called first, but it doesn't print anything. Your `f1` is called second, but it actually prints something.

The top-level `print()` call won't print anything until it has evaluated its arguments, which it does in argument order. So, `f0` is called, printing nothing but returning `1`, `f1` is called and prints the message but returns `None`. `print`'s argument values, i.e. the return values of the two functions, (`1` and `None`), are then printed in order.

tl;dr: printing and returning are different things

Comment: this answers my question. How did you know about it? I am a beginner with python. I am interested in knowing where in python official documentation I could find the same knowledge, that you shared with me through your answer.

Comment: It's not something that is explicitly stated in the documentation; the difference between a function returning a value and writing to standard output (the *side effect* of the `print` function) is universal and assumed to be understood.